# Passing a templated Object in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

In my C++ program, I have the following code:

`FileInit(gamefile, master, heap, settings);`

in the header file:

`template < typename TYPE, typename COMP>`

void FileInit(std::ifstream &gamefile, std::deque &master,
    poorman_heap &heap, settings &set);

where poorman_heap is defined in its own header file as:

`template< typename TYPE, typename COMP>
template< typename InputIterator>
poorman_heap::poorman_heap(
  InputIterator start,
  InputIterator end,
  COMP comp
) {`

But when I try to pass in a heap (in the first line), I get the error:

`` undefined reference to `void FileInit(std::basic_ifstream >&, std::deque >&, poorman_heap&, settings&)' ``

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [notld] Error 1

If I don't try to pass in heap, everything works, so I know I've linked the files correctly (that's been an issue for me in the past), but I don't know how to pass a templated object into a function.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be linked for me, but I had to add the template to FileInit.

```
template< typename TYPE, typename COMP>
class poorman_heap{
        template< typename InputIterator>
        poorman_heap( InputIterator start, InputIterator end, COMP comp ) ;
};


template< typename TYPE, typename COMP>
        template< typename InputIterator>
poorman_heap<TYPE, COMP>::poorman_heap( InputIterator start, InputIterator end, COMP comp ) {
}

class settings {};


template < typename TYPE, typename COMP>
void FileInit(std::ifstream &gamefile, std::deque<int> &master, poorman_heap<TYPE,COMP> &heap, settings &set){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must give the template parameters to poorman_heap.

```
template < typename TYPE, typename COMP>
void FileInit(std::ifstream &gamefile, std::deque &master, poorman_heap<TYPE, COMP> &heap, settings &set);
```

Comment: The InputIterator is only used in the constructor, though - for the other methods in poorman_heap, only TYPE and COMP are used.  Do I still need to have InputIterator as a template parameter?

Comment: You might also have to pass template parameters to std::deque

Comment: @camdroid, yes because its not a "type" unless it has everything for the compiler to actually generate the type at compile time.

Comment: @camdroid, what does the class declaration of poorman_heap look like?  If it has template parameters, then you must specify these when you use poorman_heap.

Comment: Outside the class declaration, it just has TYPE and COMP - InputIterator is only used as a parameter for the constructor.  I've changed it to what you said, and now I'm getting the error: `no matching function for call to âFileInit(std::ifstream&, std::deque<zombie>&, poorman_heap<zombie*, zLess>&, settings&)â
`
Right now, I just declare heap like this: `poorman_heap<zombie *, zLess > heap`  Without using new, how do I put an InputIterator in there?

Comment: is zLess a variable or a type?  Can you please put the exact declaration of the poorman_heap in your post?  You don't need the class definition, just the declaration (i.e. the template part before class, and the class line)

Comment: zLess is a struct that is based off std::less.  Here's the class definition: 
`template<typename TYPE, typename COMP = std::less<TYPE>>
class poorman_heap : public eecs281heap<TYPE, COMP> {`

Comment: I've updated the example, you have give the template parameters to poorman_heap<TYPE, COMP>.  Hola Soy Edu Feliz Navid appears to have the correct answer.

Comment: @camdroid, if this helped you, please consider upvoting.  I don't just come here for the atmosphere... :-)

Comment: haha, sure, upvoted, and thanks so much.  :)  But I'm confused as to how that differs from what I had...

Comment: @camdroid, thanks.  You had template parameters for the function FileInit.  When you pass arguments to the function, each of the arguments must be "fully qualified" meaning they must have enough information for the compiler to generate the type.  You did not pass the template parameters to the argument types.  Again, you should try Hola's answer, it looks correct.